# How to check for the accuracy of prediction

Tags: math, statistics, usage-statistics

I am doing a personal project to see how well does FIFA potential player stats predict the actual overall stat after 3 years.

1. Meaning, if a player has a potential of 85 in 2015, how accurate
   should I expect it to be to predict the overall player score in
   2018.
   Should I use R2?
2. I also want to check if the histogram of errors (potential_2015 -
   overall_2018) has a normal distribution.
   Do I need to use Chi-squared for this?
3. If the prediction is overestimating the player, I would like to know
   by how much.
   Should I use Standard Deviation on the errors?

If you have a list of key statistical tests, I would appreciate if you could list them so I can research them and learn.

Thank you,

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. For any problem like this, the first question is, can you quantify how much it costs you to be wrong (and what reward you get for being right)? This can hopefully lead to a suitable definition of an error metric.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Robert.
As for the definition of an error metric, I was just thinking on error as a deviation of the prediction.
Why do you think that defining the reward would be interesting? Is there a methoogy you were thinking about?
I am not looking to make my own model using ML (that's the only reason I could think to use that), but to test the prediction vs actual data.